# change the background of each day in a calendar?

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar API to display a calendar with reactjs everything works fine, now I am trying to add a different background to each date in a month using css.

> Note: the color can be any just different for each date

Here is what I have so far;

CSS

```
.fc-day{
  background-color: red;
}

.fc-past{
  background-color: orange;
}

.fc-future{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want if yes How?  I will appreciate any help thanks

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added what I know from docs, so what do you want me to add?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a little bit about what the specific problem is, because you didn't clarify what was wrong precisely in the code you'd tried, but from trying it myself I'm assuming the issue is that you can't make *today's* date show up in red?

If so, then it's a simple fix:

1) use the `fc-today` class to target today specifically (rather than `fc-day` which applies to all days), and

2) use `!important` so it overrides the default "today" highlight which fullCalendar always places on the current day.

```
.fc-today{
  background-color: red !important;
}

.fc-past{
  background-color: orange;
}

.fc-future{
  background-color: green;
}
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwPBxvo

Comment: I want each day to have different background color in a month

Comment: Ok. That was not clear at all. How are you deciding which colour is given to which day? Your question doesn't even include any information about what colours you want! You should update your question to make it a lot clearer and more detailed. The CSS you did show is barely relevant, if at all.

Comment: Thanks but you still haven't told us which colours you want on which days. There's no point in us making it up, we need a list. Also, what should happen to days which are not part of the current month (they sometimes appear at either end in month view) - should they be coloured as per their number, or not coloured?

Comment: P.S. hint: Each day cell has a data-attribute such as `data-date="2020-03-12"` showing the date it represents. Another hint: read this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/. Maybe you can think how to solve it yourself, now?

Comment: I said just random colors just different for each date

Comment: So you want the colours to be randomly generated each time you display the calendar?